# Add MySQL Table with python connector fails to add table without throwing error with multi=True

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have run into a very strange issue where my code below was working (I was able to add a table into the DB). After dropping a test table via the mysql workbench I am able to add a database and the code continues to run with no errors but no table is added. I have slimmed the SQL right down and attempted on different dbs. I have also restarted. Am I doing something wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import mysql.connector
import os

dirname = os.path.abspath('')
sql_filename = dirname + '\SQL_Creation\Test.sql'

class connectionsetup:
    def __init__(self):
      self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      password="")
    
      try:
        self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
        print('Conneciton Succesful')
        self.mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE AP_Application_Db_test")
        print('Database Created')
        self.mycursor.execute('USE ap_application_db_test; Create TABLE test (SERIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR(255),VIOLATION_STATUS VARCHAR(255))', multi=True)
        self.mydb.commit()
        self.mydb.close()

      except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print(err)
        print("Error Code:", err.errno)
        print("SQLSTATE", err.sqlstate)
        print("Message", err.msg   )
        
    
connectionsetup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), `cursor.execute(..., multi=True)`

> [...] returns an iterator that enables processing the result of each statement

So the code needs to be like this:

```py
for _ in self.mycursor.execute(multiple_sql_statements, multi=True):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb that now works consistently.